# How to change or reassign a variable in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I reassign a value to a variable previously assigned? I need it to works like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="variable2" select="'N'" />
....
<xsl:when test="@tip = '2' and $variable2 != 'Y'">                                                   
    <xsl:variable name="variable2" select="'Y'" />
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Variables in XSLT may only be assigned a value once.  This is done by design.  See [Why Functional languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36504/290085) for an appreciation of the motivation in general.

Rather than reassign a variable, write conditionals against the input document directly, or call a function (or named template) recursively with varying local parameters.

Anything you need to do can be done with an approach that does not require reassignment of variables.  To receive a more specific answer, provide a more specific question.

See also:

- [In XSLT how do I increment a global variable from a different
  scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/833118/290085)
- [Increment a value in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3344965/290085)
- [Use recursion effectively in XSL](https://web.archive.org/web/20130621080544/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xslrecur/)

Answer (score 11):

Just use multiple variables.  Here's your example made to work...

```xml
    <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="'N'" />
    ....
    <xsl:variable name="variable2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@tip = '2' and $variable1 != 'Y'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'Y'" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$variable1" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot - 'variables' in XSLT are actually more like constants in other languages, they cannot change value.

Answer (score 0):

Reassignable variables can be declared using an accumulator, available from XSLT version 3.0. :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0" >
      <xsl:mode use-accumulators="variable2" streamable="no"/>
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:accumulator name="variable2" initial-value="'N'">
       <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Inpayment" select="if ($value = 'N' and @tip = '2') then 'Y' else 'N' "/>
      </xsl:accumulator>

      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Inpayment">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('variable2')"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -3):

I just almost believe the viewpoint in other replies before I test.
It can really run well like that. xslt processor is saxon-he 9.8.0.12

my code ：

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs map"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="i1" select="123" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:variable name="s1" select="'abcd'" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="d1" select="234.5" as="xs:float"/>

        <!-- we test that variable v1 can be assignment multi times and it is ok.  -->
        <xsl:variable name="v1" select="$i1"/>
        v1 is: <xsl:value-of select="$v1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v1" select="$s1"/>
        v1 is: <xsl:value-of select="$v1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v1" select="$d1"/>
        v1 is: <xsl:value-of select="$v1"/>

        <xsl:variable name="map1" select="map{'haha':119, 'good':110}"/>
        <xsl:variable name="map2" select="map:put($map1, 'go', 122)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="map1" select="map:put($map2, 'hello', 999)"/>
        map1(haha) is <xsl:sequence select="$map1?haha"/>
        map1(hello) is <xsl:sequence select="$map1?hello"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[the result screenshort of the running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHqCt.png)

as your question, you can do like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="variable2" select="'N'" />
<xsl:variable name="variable2" select="hello:func1()" />

<xsl:function name="hello:func1" as="xl:string">
    .....
    <xsl:when test="@tip = '2' and $variable2 != 'Y'">                                                   
        <xsl:value-of select="'Y'" />
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: note that the xslt processor must surpport xslt 2.0 above.

Comment: This is misunderstanding both the question and what's happening in your test. See my comment to your other post with the same claim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637219/how-do-i-reassign-a-variable-in-xslt#comment104495555_59131847

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I have append some words in my answer. "as your question, you can do like that:....."