# Incrementing a variable in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following variable quarter defined and I want to increment it's current value by one in my XSL sheet if it's value does not equal 4.

I have the following code:

```
  <xsl:if test="not($quarter=4)">
      </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$quarter+1" />
  </xsl:if>
```

But this does not work - does anyone have an idea of how I can add 1 to my $quarter variable?

Comment: [Reassign xsl variable value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255139/reassign-xsl-variable-value)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work due to the /xsl:text tag. Does the if statement really work? Try by outputing the variable with xsl:message. Aside from that, check that the  variable actually stores a number, and, if it does, try explicitely casting the variable contents as a number using an xpath function.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is correct (assuming `$quarter` is a valid XSL number variable, in case you may use `number($quarter)+1`). What's wrong is `<xsl:text>` node, you do not have a valid XML file:

```
<xsl:if test="not($quarter=4)">
    </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$quarter+1" />
</xsl:if>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<xsl:if test="not($quarter=4)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$quarter+1" />
</xsl:if>
```

Note that a) you used closing tag `</xsl:text>` instead of opening one and b) as noted by Micheal `<xsl:text>` can contain only text, no child elements.

Comment: It should also be noted that the value of `$quarter` is not actually being changed. (The variable is not actually incremented.) It's only the results of `$quarter + 1` that are being output.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - The xsl:text element cannot have another element inside, it can only contain text.