# Choose with for-each inside?

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a parameter`ignoreAttributes` which is a comma separated list of things to look for. I want to set a variable `copyAttrib` to be equal to whether any of them are exactly matched by `name()`.

If `xsl` were a procedural language where variables could be reassigned, I'd use something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="copyAttrib" select="true()">
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($ignoreAttributes,',')">
    <xsl:if test="compare(., name()) != 0">
        <xsl:variable name="copyAttrib" select="false()"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Unfortunately, I can't do that, because `xsl` is functional (so says [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255959/901641)). So variables can only be assigned once.

I think the solution would look something like:

```
<vsl:variable name="copyAttrib">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($ignoreAttributes, ',')">
                <xsl:if test="compare(., name()) != 0"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Obviously not exactly that (otherwise I wouldn't be asking.)

I know that I could bypass the `tokenize` and `for-each` loop by just using `replaces` on ignoreAttributes and changing all the `,` to `|` and then using `matches`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible because then I need to deal with the possibility that `ignoreAttributes` (which the user provides) might contain some special characters that will change the regex pattern and escape them all.

Comment: Consider to show us a minimal but complete snippet of XML input, XSLT code and output you want. I am afraid inside for your for-each with `tokenize` the context item is a string so doing `name()` for any outside context node is not going to work. You can however perhaps simply use `<xsl:variable name="copyAttrib" select="name() = tokenize($ignoreAttribute, ',')"/>` which would make the variable true if the name of the context node is equal to at least one token.

Comment: Can we assume that because you are using tokenize() you are looking for an XSLT 2.0 solution? You really need to say (using the tag xslt_1.0 or xslt_2.0) because otherwise people answering the question can waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a parameterignoreAttributes which is a comma separated list of things to look for. I want to set a variable copyAttrib to be equal to whether any of them are exactly matched by name().

That sounds to me like

```
<xsl:variable name="copyAttrib" as="xs:boolean"
  select="tokenize($parameterignoreAttributes, ',') = name()"/>
```

You say:

> Unfortunately, I can't do that, because xsl is functional

when what you mean is: "Fortunately, I don't need to do that, because XSLT is functional".

Comment: So `=` can mean `contains`? Which versions of XSLT does this work with?

Comment: If you're using XSLT/XPath you really shouldn't need to ask that question. If you don't know how "=" works in XPath (or whatever other language you write in), then the code you write is going to give you a lot of surprises. Yes, X=Y in XPath means "some item in X is equal to some item in Y".

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT-1.0 way of doing this is by using a recursive, named template:

```
  <xsl:template name="copyAttrib">
    <xsl:param name="attribs" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(substring-before($attribs,',')) = normalize-space(name(.))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space($attribs) = ''">
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="copyAttrib">
            <xsl:with-param name="attribs" select="substring-after($attribs,',')" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Apply this template onto the current, the selected, node and wrap it in a `<xsl:variable>`:

```
<xsl:variable name="copyAttribResult">
  <xsl:call-template name="copyAttrib">
    <xsl:with-param name="attribs" select="'a,b,c,...commaSeparatedValues...'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

to get either `true` or `false` as a result.

Comment: Is `call-template` not available in XSLT-2.0? I don't see it in my documentation.

Comment: Of course it's available. It's just used far less often, because functions are much more convenient.