# Count the parent elements and return them in string XSLT 2

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to count the parent elements and return count in String format. I have mentioned tried code below.

Input:

```
<node>
    <dot>
        <title>paragaraph 12</title>
    </dot>
    <dot>
        <dot>
            <dot>
                <ttle>paragaraph 23</ttle>
            </dot>
        </dot>
    </dot>
    <dot>
        <dot>
            <title>paragaraph 24</title>
        </dot>
    </dot>
</node>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="title[parent::dot]">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(parent::dot)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
<output>
    <out type="One">paragaraph 12</out>
    <out type="Three">paragaraph 23</out>
    <out type="Two">paragaraph 24</out>
</output>
```

Explain output:

`<out type="One">paragaraph 12</out>` --> here there are one `<dot>` above title. so `@type` should be as `One`

`<out type="One">paragaraph 23</out>` --> here there are three `<dot>` above title. so `@type` should be as `Three`

`<out type="One">paragaraph 24</out>` --> here there are two `<dot>` above title. so `@type` should be as `Two`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsl:number` with `format="Ww"` should produce the right output:

```
  <xsl:template match="dot/title">
      <out>
          <xsl:attribute name="count">
              <xsl:number format="Ww" value="count(ancestor::dot)"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </out>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the ancestor-axis:

```
  <xsl:template match="title[parent::dot]">
    <xsl:element name="out">
      <xsl:attribute name="type" select="count(ancestor::dot)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

To convert the numbers to words check out this question: [Convert Number into english Word-Meaning using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948755/convert-number-into-english-word-meaning-using-xslt)